# Spring MVC/Thymeleaf: two-dimensional iteration through Map where each value is a set

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I'm using this data structure: `Map<String,Set<String>>` and I want to iterate through both dimensions in Thymeleaf. The map is a set of pairs where a directory is assigned to the files that are in this directory.

```
<table th:each="subdirectory : ${subdirectories}">
    <tr th:each="files : ${subdirectories[__${subdirectory}__]}">
        <td th:each="file: ${files}" th:text="file"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But all it renders are three empty `<table></tables>`. There is definitely data in the map.

My data structure looks like this:

```
{
"dirA/dir1": [
"file1.ext"
],
"dirA/dir2": [
"file1.ext",
"file2.ext"
]
}
```

For each directorypath I'd like to get a table (or a list) with all the files. Don't know how to get the value from the map and iterate through it.

Comment: A filesystem is a tree structure, are you trying to flatten it? The data structure has two collections, but your template has 3 loops. Could you perhaps write how you would iterate over the structure in pure Java.

Comment: I explicitly don't want/need a tree structure here.
My data structure looks like this:
    {
    "dirA/dir1": [
    "file1.ext"
    ],
    "dirA/dir2": [
    "file1.ext",
    "file2.ext"
    ]
    }

See my edited question for proper formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since iteration over a map returns an Entry (http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#iterable-values) you can use should access the value of the subdirectory (entry).

```
<table th:each="subdirectory : ${subdirectories}">
  <tr th:each="files : ${subdirectory.value}">
    <td th:each="file: ${files}" th:text="${file}"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you want to display the directory, you can use `${subdirectory.key}`

(Also fixed the variable in the variable in the td's `th:text`)

Answer (score 0):

With a lot of try and error and a lot of using Google I found the following, working solution:

```
<table th:each="subdirectory : ${subdirectories}">
    <thead>
        <th th:text="${subdirectory.key}"></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each="file : ${subdirectory.value}">
            <td th:text="${file}"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```